# Creating shared lock using openmp

Tags: c++, locking, openmp, critical-section

I normally use the

```
#pragma omp critical(lock)
{ ... }
```

directive when I need to make sure only one thread is executing a given piece of code.

So what I am looking for is a way to implement shared locks and exclusive locks using something similar. I have multiple threads that can read or write a variable. When a thread is writing, it will block all other threads from reading or writing. However reading the variable shouldnt block anything. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenMP has no support for reader-writer locks. You could instead use other libraries like Boost that offers [shared_lock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.shared_lock).